# Ограничение меню по высоте

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

Есть простой список меню и мне нужно что бы при добавлении элементов они просто шли друг под другом и делились на 2 колонки сохраняя изначальный вид меню.
Но такая картина не получается, и элементы просто создают 3, 4, 5 и т.д. колонки и не растягивают список.

```css
.main-footer__menu-inner {
  display: flex;
}

.main-footer__menu-box {
  width: 50%;
}

.menu-list {
  width: 76%;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu-list__item {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-footer__menu-box">
  <h3>Разделы сайта</h3>
  <ul class="menu-list">
    <li class="menu-list__item">
      <a href="#">О компании</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list__item">
      <a href="#">Продукты</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list__item">
      <a href="#">Производство печатных плат</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list__item">
      <a href="#">Монтаж печатных плат</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list__item">
      <a href="#">Комплектующие</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list__item">
      <a href="#">Доставка</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-list__item">
      <a href="#">Контакты</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я правильно понимаю вопрос? Так должно быть?

```css
.menu-list li {
  width: 49%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-footer__menu-inner">
  <div class="main-footer__menu-box">
    <h3>Разделы сайта</h3>
    <ul class="menu-list">
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">О компании</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Продукты</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Производство печатных плат</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Монтаж печатных плат</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Комплектующие</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Доставка</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Контакты</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">О компании</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Продукты</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Производство печатных плат</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Монтаж печатных плат</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Комплектующие</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Доставка</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Контакты</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">О компании</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Продукты</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Производство печатных плат</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Монтаж печатных плат</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Комплектующие</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Доставка</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Контакты</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">О компании</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Продукты</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Производство печатных плат</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Монтаж печатных плат</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Комплектующие</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Доставка</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Контакты</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">О компании</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Продукты</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Производство печатных плат</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Монтаж печатных плат</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Комплектующие</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Доставка</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Контакты</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">О компании</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Продукты</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Производство печатных плат</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Монтаж печатных плат</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Комплектующие</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Доставка</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-list__item">
        <a href="#">Контакты</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да вы правильно поняли вопрос. Спасибо!
P.S. Решил свою проблему только что сам, оказывается просто высоту в процентах надо было задать... эээээх :D

Comment: А ну да, только я с флоатами не сильно люблю работать. Флексы как-то попроще. И получилось сделать это благодаря обёртке, списку задал высоту в процентах а обёртке наоборот ограничил max-height, это сработало как надо.